# Не могу вывести balance с БД по id

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

Есть база данных куда вносится id пользователя,получаемый from_user,при входе пользователь получает n токенов .При нажатии на кнопку мой профиль пользователь получает свой id,а так же баланс.Проблема в том что выводится некоректное значение баланса,а если быть точнее пустое поле,не могу понять в чем проблема,помогите разобраться.Ниже предоставил строчки кода:

```
if call.data == 'profil':
        conn = connect('DBGPT.sql')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(f"SELECT balance FROM People WHERE user = 'message.from_user.id'")
        resultsa = cur.fetchall()
        bal = ''
        for el in resultsa:
            bal += {el[0]}
        
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text=f"Ваш id:{call.message.chat.id}\n\nНа данный момент вам доступно токенов запроса:{bal}")
```

Comment: `user = 'message.from_user.id'` — кто вас учил так писать sql-запросы?

Comment: Сам учился,если проблема именно в этом,то что нужно исправить?

Comment: `f"SELECT balance FROM People WHERE user = {message.from_user.id}"`

Comment: Но ситуацию это не исправило бот выдает пустую строчку

Comment: @ИванИпатов обучать человека sql-инъекциям тоже не надо

Answer (score 0):

Скопировал из коментариев:

```
f"SELECT balance FROM People WHERE user = {message.from_user.id}"
```

Я давно не пользовался connector-ом, перешёл на ORM
Но мне квжеться проблема в этой части кода

```
for el in resultsa:
            bal += {el[0]}
```

resultsa должен вроде возвращать сразу строку по типу (id, user_id, bal) ну і нужно просто resultsa[2]
Могу ошибаться

Comment: Копировать sql-инъекцию из комментария в ответ тем более не надо